# Windows 8.1 Blender UI Broken?

Tags: modeling, interface, windows

This has happened to me in the past, and the problem was fixed on its own after a long time. Unfortunately, I don't really want to wait that long and was wondering if there was a fix in the future. I am running Windows 8.1 and when I install blender from the website, the UI buttons are red, which can be seen in the image below. When downloading blender from Steam, I get a different result showing the red as usual, but then covers it with black buttons and a black screen, which I also have shown a picture of, but the application still seems broken.[Screen from blender website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SBA6.png)[image: Steam Version]